# transform scale(1) does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, css-transforms, microsoft-edge

I have problems performing a simple transform: `scale()` in Microsoft Edge.
I created a [simple test case](http://codepen.io/erotte/pen/KrBOvA) that should show a submenu on hover via scaling the `scaleX()` property. This should work in any browser. 
In Edge it fails as long as the value I like to scale to is 1, but works if it's 1.0001 or 0.999999, for example. This also fails with `scale()` and `scale3d()`.

```css
* {
  font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
li {
  padding: 0.2em 1.4em
}
.root > li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #adc;
}
li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #cde;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200px
}

li.one:hover > ul {
  transform: scaleY(1.0001) ;
}


li.two:hover > ul {
  transform: scaleY(1.0) ;
}

li.three:hover > ul {
  transform: none ;
}


.content {
  background: #fed;
  min-height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='root'>
  <li class='one'>hover me, it works
    <ul>
      <li>ding</li>
      <li>dong</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
  <li class='two'>me not, in IE Edge
    <ul>
      <li>ding</li>
      <li>dong</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
  <li class='three'>got it!
    <ul>
      <li><code>transform: none</code></li>
      <li>does the trick!</li>
      <li>so stupid!</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
<h1>Huhuuuh,</h1>
  <p>Obviously IE Edge (current Version on a Surface Pro) has a problem with hiding and showing elements via a scale transforms to factor 1. As long as its not Integer(1) like 0.9999 or 1.0001, it works.
  </p>
  <p>Just try out here and change the values to get sure.</p>
<p>
My IE Version:
  <br />
Microsoft Edge 25.10568.0.0
<br />
Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10568.0.0  
  </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: It's Microsoft Edge, not IE Edge, by the way. IE is a different browser entirely.

Comment: I filed [a bug against Microsoft Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8347513/) on the basis of Interoperability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200281(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The function `scale(1, 1)` leaves the element **unchanged**.

So it seems in such cases IE and EDGE behave like no changes should be done rather than scale an element to its original size.

If there're no other transformations, it's possible to reset the applied transformation:

```
transform: none;
```

Comment: …but it has been scaled to to `scale(0,0)` before.
So, is there an option to reset the element to its original scale?

Comment: yes, I also just got it and fixed it in the example. So simple and stupid, can't believe that…
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

if you set an original width and height then `transform: scale(1, 1);` will work, but otherwise, you will not be able to reset your transformation like this. Scale transforms from the given w/h, which in the case of it having being scaled to 0,0 would be 0 and 0 - therein lies the problem. So setting an original width and height is the best way to go

```css
div {
    margin:120px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -ms-transform: scale(0,0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(0,0); /* Standard syntax */
}
#wrapper{transform:scale(1,1);}
body{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<p>This div uses scale (1, 1) and it works because a w/h have been set in the css</p>

<div>
This div element is scaled to 0
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the way, scale is unsupported on Opera mini, and also has issues on FF, http://caniuse.com/#search=transform